# Redux toolkit error parsing non JSON response

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying out redux toolkit and currently have the following slice and mutation:

```
export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://localhost:3000",
    credentials: "include",
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      const token = (getState() as RootState).authentication.token;

      if (token) {
        headers.set("authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
      }

      return headers;
    }
  }),
  endpoints(builder) {
    return {
      //skipped other endpoints
      whoAmI: builder.mutation<string, void>({
        query(){
          return {
            url: "user/whoAmI",
            method: "GET"
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
});
```

When I trigger the whoAmI mutation I get an error saying "SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1 (line 1 column 2)" which makes me think redux currently expects a JSON to come back form the user/whoAmI endpoint, the actual response is just a GUID containing the logged user's id.

How can I configure this endpoint to expect a string rather than a JSON so I avoid this error and fetch the id?

Answer (score 0):

I found the `responseHandler` option solves my issue:

```
  whoAmI: builder.mutation<string, void>({
    query(){
      return {
        url: "user/whoAmI",
        method: "GET",
        responseHandler: (response) => response.text()
      }
    }
  })
```

This will make RTK treat the response for this request as plain text.

Source: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#parsing-a-response